# How to iterate over an array posted by jquery (ajax) in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

This is the var_dump of a post I am sending to PHP via AJAX

```
array (size=1)
  'myArray' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'event=100%20Yard%20Back%20Stroke&swimmername=john doe&lane=1&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=2&swimmername2=john doe' (length=164)
      1 => string 'event=100%20Yard%20Back%20Stroke&swimmername=john doe&lane=3&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=4&swimmername2=john doe' (length=164)
      2 => string 'event=100%20Yard%20Back%20Stroke&swimmername=john doe&lane=5&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=6&swimmername2=john doe' (length=164)
```

How can I iterate through each and assign 3 values to each row of 11 elements

```
$event =  event=100 Yard Back Stroke 
$swimmername = john doe
$lane = 5
.. etc
```

so I can INSERT each row (3 in this case) into my database

PHP Code

```
var_dump($_POST);

foreach($_POST as $data)
{


    if(isset($data['event'])){$event = $data['event'];}
    if(isset($data['swimmername'])){$name = $data['swimmername'];}
    if(isset($data['lane'])){$lane =  $data['lane'];}
    if(isset($data['place'])){$place = $data['place'];}
    if(isset($data['time'])){$time =  $data['time'];}
    if(isset($data['scoreA'])){$score = $data['scoreA'];}
    if(isset($data['scoreB'])){$score2 =  $data['scoreB'];}
    if(isset($data['time2'])){$time2 = $data['time2'];}
    if(isset($data['lane2'])){$lane2 =  $data['lane2'];}
    if(isset($data['place2'])){$place2 =  $data['place2'];}
    if(isset($data['swimmername2'])){$name2 = $data['swimmername2'];}


}
```

Comment: I have tried what I show in the comments above.

Comment: There are no comments above!

Comment: I have no clue how to do it , that's why I posted the question

Comment: Sorry I meant question above

Comment: you tried doing the console.log() of the response you get? Show us what is that?

Comment: The response shows the var_dump (in original question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94982/discussion-between-user5451365-and-void).

Answer (score 0):

Each element of your array is a single string. 
Use explode() with '&' as the delimiter to put each string into an array of the individual elements. Then, assign the elements of that new array to the variables you need for the remainder of your program.

Comment: How do i access the string? Is it myArray[0]?
I am new to PHP, so I apologize for the level of question

Comment: You can find out by doing a VAR_DUMP of $data inside your foreach